# How does virtual inheritance work?

Tags: c++, memory, inheritance, virtual

1. Does virtual inheritance use vTable? If yes or no, Then how it implemented
2. How Virtual inheritance behave in memory?
3. Any other alternative for virtual inheritance

Really appreciate a conceptual explanation.

Comment: It is Implementation dependent, in strict technical terms it is *Unspecified*, the C++ standard only describes the behavior which virtual inheritance has to offer but it does not specify how it should be implemented.It is left out as an detail for implementations & they ar not needed to specify this detail.Having said that most(*read all known*) of the compilers do use an virtual table and pointer mechanism.

Comment: Having said the above, don't think the Q is irrelevant or not a real Q at all.All compilers do use a similar mechanism and though it is not needed to know the implementation detail, it doesn't hurt to know it.Also, this Q gets asked so many times it would make a nice C++-faq if someone takes out time and answers it convincingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual inheritance is implemented in different way depending on the compiler.

1) Yes, both vc and gcc use vTable pointer. But vc has another pointer  ref as virtual base pointer.

2) For a classical virtual inheritance, like Left < Top; Right < Top; Bottom < Left and Right
The stack should be like this:

```
Left.vptr  // -> to its vtable

Left::element_in_left

Right.vptr

Right::element_in_right

Bottom::element_in_bottom

Top::element_in_top
```

Programs use vptr to find vtable, for gcc, there is a virtual base offset value in viable. vptr + base offset will give the parent address.

3) I'm not sure what do you mean. There are different ways to implement it in C++ compilers. And other languages have their ways to bind functions.

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems quit complex! could you recommend me some simple article or book for read about this.

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya I've read these knowledge in my native language posts, so I'm not familiar with books in English. I guess you could search for "c++ memory layout virtual inheritance" in google, there are lots of great posts.